# Two quadrilateral out of a hexagon

Tags: logical-deduction, geometry

We have a hexagon shown as below with two quadrilaterals:

[image]

> Your task is:
>
> - Slice hexagon into two pieces and combine these pieces to find shape $a$
> - Slice hexagon into three pieces and combine these pieces to find shape $b$

Note: There is no scale in the pictures as you would guess.

Comment: Your shape a has a long side that is twice as long as its short side. Shouldn't it be 3 times as long for the 2-piece solution to work?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis which shape are you are talking about? there are 3 shapes in total.

Comment: Shape a. Yours consists essentially of 4 equilateral triangles stuck together in a row, but it should be like 6 in a row. It should be longer than it is now. It is not a problem with the scale/size, it is a problem with the shape.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I see, the aim was just to draw parallel quadrilateral. I understand what u meant now, I can fix it with better shapes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming size isn't preserved:

Shape a:

> [image: A]

Shape b:

> [image: B]

Comment: For part a, your final shape has one side that is 3 times as long as the other. I think in the shape in the problem statement it is only about twice as long. This could be a mistake on Oray's part cause I really don't see how else you could do it with 2 pieces.